# Verify autofs is not enabled in Slackware 14.2 - Disabling Automount

Tags: linux, slackware, systemctl

I want to disable automounting in Slackware. With this goal I want to verify if autofs is enabled. Below are the commands that I saw which is applicable in other Linux Distributions :

```
chkconfig --list autofs
systemctl is-enabled autofs
ls /etc/rc*.d | grep autofs
```

chkconfig and systemctl are not applicable in Slackware. What is the equivalent commands I can use in Slackware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the eXecutable bit on /etc/rc.d/rc.autofs:

`ls -l /etc/rc.d/rc.autofs`

Stop: `# sh /etc/rc.d/rc.autofs stop`

Disable: `# chmod a-x /etc/rc.d/rc.autofs`

Enable: `# chmod a+x /etc/rc.d/rc.autofs`

rc.autofs and other services in Slackware starts with check for eXecutable bit, rc.autofs starts from rc.M on boot with:

`if [ -x /etc/rc.d/rc.autofs ]; then`

slackbook about this: https://www.slackbook.org/html/system-configuration.html#SYSTEM-CONFIGURATION-RCD